# C++ Inheritance - Overriding Function, including using "::"s, .h files & .cpp files

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, header-files

I have looked all over and I can't find any resources on this involving the `::` operator.

I have 2 classes: `A` and `B`. I also have another class `C`.

`B` inherits from `A`, as does `C`.

`A` contains a method called `d`:

`A`'s `.h` file:

```
class A
{
public:
    ...
    void d();
};
```

`A`'s `.cpp` file:

```
...
void A::d()
{
    ...
}
```

If I have a `B` or a `C`, and I run their `d`, this method should be run if `B` or `C` do not have their own overridden `d`.

I want to override `d` in `B`, however it isn't clear to me how I do this. Should I be doing this inside `B`'s `.cpp` file?:

```
void A::d()
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
void B::d()
{
    ...
}
```

and declare it in `B`'s `.h` file?

Or should the function be `virtual`?

Comment: It looks like it's time for a good [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: make the function virtual. If A is abstract then make it private virtual. And then override the function with override keyword in sub class. In C++ the function needs to be virtual there is no automatic invocation like in Java.

Comment: @4386427: It's the "scope resolution operator".

Answer (score 4):

Overriding is a property of *virtual* member functions, and it is part of a *class definition*.

Schematically, you want:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void d() { /* A's implementation */ }
};

struct B : A
{
    void d() override { /* B's override of A::d */ }
};

struct C : A
{
}:
```

Usage: suppose you have this function:

```
void g(A & a) { a.d(); }
```

Then:

```
B b;
g(b);   // calls b's B::d

C c;
g(c);   // calls c's A::d on the A-subobject of c
```

(How you split your code into different files has nothing to do with inheritance and overriding.)

Comment: Consider adding some information on how this behavior changes if `A::d()` is not marked as `virtual`.